# Creating a user called 'root'

Tags: kvm-virtualization, virtualization

I am creating Virtual Machines using the [ubuntu-vm-builder](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/ubuntu-vm-builder.1.html).

The syntax goes something like this:

```
ubuntu-vm-builder kvm precise \  
              --domain newvm \  
              --dest newvm \  
              --arch i386 \  
              --hostname hostnameformyvm \  
              --mem 256 \  
              --user john \  
              --pass doe \  
              --ip 192.168.0.12 \  
              --mask 255.255.255.0 \  
              --net 192.168.0.0 \  
              --bcast 192.168.0.255 \  
              --gw 192.168.0.1 \  
              --dns 192.168.0.1 \  
              --mirror http://archive.localubuntumirror.net/ubuntu \  
              --components main,universe \  
              --addpkg acpid \   
              --addpkg vim \  
              --addpkg openssh-server \  
              --addpkg avahi-daemon \  
              --libvirt qemu:///system ;
```

**I need to enable the 'root' user account** after creating each of my VMs (and supply a password for it).

I was just wondering whether I can take this short-cut of supplying the username (`--user`) as `root` in this command itself. If I supply username as `root` to create my VMs, am I creating/enabling *the* root user, or just creating a user named as root?

*p.s.: any better ways to achieve my task are also welcome. But I don't want to manually meddle with each VM after its creation*

Comment: @user68186: No. This question is obviously about modifying an installation image to enable the root account, not how to enable it *after* the installation.

Comment: @DavidFoerster retracted.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply create one VM, configured as you like and clone it. Seems like a reasonable alternative. You might also find [this related post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/265623/is-there-a-modern-equivalent-of-python-vm-builder) interesting.